# Read binary data into R efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe

From a text file I'm reading in binary data structured like this:

```
0101010100101010101010101010
1010101001010101010101010111
1111101010101010100101010101
```

The file has 800 lines. Every line is equally long (but that varies between files, so it doesn't make sense to hard code it). I want the input stored in a data frame, in which every line is a row, and every two numbers are stored in different columns, for example:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
0      1    0    1
```

Currently I am doing it like this

```
as.matrix(read.table(text=gsub("", ' ', readLines("input"))))->g
```

However, that takes too long as there are roughly 70,000 0/1's in each line.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend exploring `read_fwf` from the "readr" package. You can do something like this:

```
library(readr)
len <- nchar(readLines("yourfile.txt", n = 1))
read_fwf("yourfile.txt", fwf_widths(rep(1, len)))
```

Alternatively, you can try [the "iotools" package](https://github.com/s-u/iotools), which might be faster:

```
library(iotools)
len <- nchar(readLines("yourfile.txt", n = 1))
input.file("yourfile.txt", formatter = dstrfw, 
            col_types = rep("integer", len), widths = rep(1, len))
```

Here's a small POC:

```
a <- tempfile()

writeLines("0101010100101010101010101010
1010101001010101010101010111
1111101010101010100101010101", a)

len <- nchar(readLines(a, n = 1))

library(readr)
read_fwf(a, fwf_widths(rep(1, len)))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 28]
# 
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28
# 1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
# 2  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
# 3  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

---

The dimensions of your data does seem to make `read_fwf` choke. I did a small test to compare the "iotools" approach with `awk` + `fread`.

Here is the sample data:

```
## Creates a file named "somefile.txt"
set.seed(1)
A <- replicate(10, sample(0:1, 70000, TRUE), FALSE)
A <- sapply(A, paste, collapse = "")
writeLines(rep(A, 800/length(A)), "somefile.txt")
```

Here are the functions and results. I've written the functions such that you should be able to try them on your actual data to see which works out best for you.

Obviously, it seems like `readr` is out of the picture at this stage :-)

```
Freadr <- function(infile = "somefile.txt") {
  len <- nchar(readLines(infile, n = 1))
  read_fwf(infile, fwf_widths(rep(1, len)))
}
system.time(temp1 <- Freadr())
# |===============================================================| 100%   53 MB
#    user  system elapsed 
# 466.740   0.384 466.506 

Fiotools <- function(infile = "somefile.txt") {
  len <- nchar(readLines(infile, n = 1))
  input.file(infile, formatter = dstrfw, 
             col_types = rep("integer", len), widths = rep(1, len))
}
system.time(temp2 <- Fiotools())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   7.248   0.016   7.273 

Fawk <- function(infile = "somefile.txt") {
  cmd <- sprintf("awk '{gsub(/./,\"&,\", $1);print $1}' %s", infile)
  fread(cmd)
}
system.time(temp3 <- Fawk())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  12.948   0.156  13.109
```

For that matter, using base R is not too bad either:

```
fun4 <- function(infile = "somefile.txt") {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(readLines(infile), "", TRUE), as.numeric))
}
system.time(fun4())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   9.056   0.260   9.304
```

The result there is a `matrix`, so you may need to add a couple of seconds for conversion to a `data.frame` or a `data.table` if that's really what you want.

Comment: is there maybe also a solution with fread? It is a bit faster than the solutions from the readr package and I got a problem installing it.....

Comment: @heinheo, can you try the "iotools" alternative I shared. In my experience, it's very fast.

Comment: do you know how I could dynamically paste my file into you Fawk function without having to redefine it anyway? can I pass the filename as an argument  maybe?

Comment: @heinheo, I've already done that by providing the "infile" argument. So, if your file is "someotherfile.txt", you should be able to just run `Fawk("someotherfile.txt")`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: really dont knwo which answer to accept as both are very good

Answer (score 7):

You could `pipe` with `awk`

```
read.table(pipe("awk '{gsub(/./,\"& \", $1);print $1}' yourfile.txt"))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
#1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
#2  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
#3  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
#  V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28
#1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
#2   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
#3   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Or

```
read.table(pipe("awk '{gsub(\"\",\" \", $1);print $1}' yourfile.txt"))
```

`fread` can also be combined with `awk`

```
library(data.table)
fread("awk '{gsub(/./,\"&,\", $1);print $1}' yourfile.txt")
```

Using a similar dataset as the OP's dataset,

```
library(stringi)
write.table(stri_rand_strings(800,70000, '[0-1]'), file='binary1.txt',
         row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

system.time(fread("awk '{gsub(/./,\"&,\", $1);print $1}' binary1.txt"))
#  user  system elapsed 
#16.444   0.108  16.542
```

Comment: how could I dynamically change the input files in the fread("awk '{gsub(/./,\"&,\", $1);print $1}' yourfile.txt") command if I want to write in a loop "your_file_1.txt" and then in the next iteration "your_file_2.txt"???

Comment: @heinheo Wouldn't the `sprintf` from `AnandaMahto's post help

Comment: @heinheo, if you have a list of the files that you need to read in, you can just use a `for` loop or `lapply` with the `Fawk` function I shared. I don't see the hangup....

Comment: @heinheo It worked for a couple of files I created. `lst <- lapply(list.files(pattern='binary\\d+.txt'), Fawk); sapply(lst, dim)
#      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]   800   800
[2,] 70001 70001`

Comment: really dont knwo which answer to accept as both are very good

Answer (score 2):

From a subsequent question, from the structure of the data, and from the original solution it seems that you'd like a matrix (since all columns are of the same type) rather than a data.frame indicated in the body of the question (and causing problems down-stream!). The data doesn't seem too big, so read it in and split into individual letters

```
lns = strsplit(readLines("somefile.txt"), "")
```

Then unlist, match strings to integer, and reshape as matrix

```
v = match(unlist(lns), c("0", "1")) - 1L
m = matrix(v, nrow=length(lns), byrow=TRUE)
```

Or as a function

```
input2matrix <- function(fname) {
    lns = strsplit(readLines("somefile.txt"), "")
    v = match(unlist(lns), c("0", "1")) - 1L
    matrix(v, nrow=length(lns), byrow=TRUE)
}
```

This takes about 5s for the 800 x 70000 line example. From comparison with other responses, it is also faster than all other solutions (I couldn't get iotools to install easily, complaining about C-level missing symbol Rspace) and does not making assumptions about OS and availability of OS tools (and knowledge of those tools in addition to R!).

Comment: This does seem to have a performance edge against my base R approach. +1